# On the Windows command line, how do I feed output from cat into my java main method?

Tags: java, windows, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I can't figure out how to get the command line command "cat" and my trivial Java program to work together in a Windows command line. In the same way that it's common in Linux to use:

```
cat *.* | grep stackoverflow
```

I would like to do this in Windows:

```
cat inputfile.txt | java Boil
```

I can't get cat to feed Boil though. As you can see below, the command line command "cat" works fine, and the Boil program works fine *if* I supply it with parameters in the format "java Boil these are parameters".

My Boil.java code

```
// Boil down lines of input code to just ;{}( and )
//          and enjoy seeing the patterns
public class Boil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int outputCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < args[i].length(); j++) {
                if (args[i].charAt(j) == ';' 
                        || args[i].charAt(j) == '(' 
                        || args[i].charAt(j) == ')' 
                        || args[i].charAt(j) == '{' 
                        || args[i].charAt(j) == '}') {
                    System.out.print(args[i].charAt(j));
                    outputCounter++;
                    if (outputCounter >= 80) {
                        System.out.print("\n");
                        outputCounter = 0;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know this could be better optimized :)

From my C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe, 'Administrator: cmd.exe' Windows command line window, running on a computer with Windows 7 Professional SP1 32 bit OS:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>cd ../../workspace1/Boil/bin

C:\workspace1\Boil\bin>ls
Boil.class     inputfile.txt

C:\workspace1\Boil\bin>cat inputfile.txt
This is a sample text file() with {
        multiple lines!;
}
C:\workspace1\Boil\bin>java Boil this should print nothing

C:\workspace1\Boil\bin>java Boil this should print a semicolon; ok?
;
C:\workspace1\Boil\bin>java Boil test all good chars ;(){}
;(){}
C:\workspace1\Boil\bin>cat inputfile.txt | java Boil

C:\workspace1\Boil\bin>java Boil < inputfile.txt

C:\workspace1\Boil\bin>java Boil < cat inputfile.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\workspace1\Boil\bin>cat inputfile.txt > java Boil
cat: Boil: No such file or directory

C:\workspace1\Boil\bin>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 0666-2986

 Directory of C:\workspace1\Boil\bin

11/20/2013  04:29 PM    <DIR>          .
11/20/2013  04:29 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/20/2013  02:28 PM               864 Boil.class
11/20/2013  04:22 PM                57 inputfile.txt
11/20/2013  04:29 PM                57 java
               3 File(s)            978 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  872,764,809,216 bytes free

C:\workspace1\Boil\bin>cat java
This is a sample text file() with {
        multiple lines!;
}
C:\workspace1\Boil\bin>rm java
```

Any thoughts much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to read the lines as arguments, you should be reading from the standard input stream.

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = 
                  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String input;

    while((input = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(input);
    }

} catch (IOException io){
    io.printStackTrace();
}
```

Piping means passing the output stream (STDOUT) to another command as STDIN. In this example, Boil nor grep get any arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. The command line now shows this: C:\workspace1\Boil\src>cat inputfile.txt | java Boil ------command line output---------
    (){;}

Answer (score 0):

If your command is `java Boil`, there are no arguments.  Therefore, none of the code in your loop will ever execute.  You're trying to get the `cat` command to feed its output into the **arguments** of the command, but you can't do that in Windows.  (Using `|` doesn't do that on Unix/Linux, either.  You have to use backticks to accomplish that.  But Windows doesn't support backticks.)

(P.S. The command you gave on Linux:

```
cat *.* | grep stackoverflow
```

doesn't do what you seem to think it does.  After the pattern, "`stackoverflow`", `grep` expects to see file names of files to search, or if there aren't any, it uses standard input.  `|` pipes the output of `cat` to `grep`'s standard input, not to the command-line arguments.  You couldn't use this to use the output of `cat` as the *pattern* for `grep` [unless there's some way to use the `-f` option for this].)